# Run Safari 4 and 5 on the same PC?

Tags: browser, html, safari, css

With the new release of 5 is it possible to run Safari 4 and 5 on the same PC at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using portable versions?
http://worldforfree.net/software/1146041979-apple-safari-4053017-portable.html
http://worldforfree.net/software/1146166421-apple-safari-50-portable.html
(Not sure about this site, you can check the files with VirusTotal.)